# Strange Scala Syntax wherein Future is mapped such that "==" and "!=" appear with only one operand (not two)

Tags: scala, syntax, boolean, operators, future

I came across a puzzling, but interesting,  code construct that I whittled down to a small example, and that
I still have trouble wrapping my head around.

The example is shown below. Note that I have a simple Future that immediately returns a String. I map this
to a comparison of the Future itself using !=  and ==

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Dummy extends App {
  val taskReturningString: Future[String] =  Future{ "foo"}

  val falseResult: Future[Boolean] = taskReturningString.map(taskReturningString ==)
  System.out.println("false result:" + Await.result(falseResult, 0 nanos) )

  val trueResult: Future[Boolean] = taskReturningString.map(taskReturningString !=)
  System.out.println("true result:" + Await.result(trueResult, 0 nanos) )
}
```

The output is

```
    false result:false
    true result:true
```

But I'm not sure why I got those results.     In the case of ==, and !=  the first item being compared is
'taskReturningString'  -- the Future.  But what is it being compared to ?     I am assuming that what is happening
is a comparison, but I've never seen a case where the operators == and != appear with one operand instead of two.

Answer (score 4):

That behavior is due to `eta expansion`. Those `map` need a function `String => Boolean` (because type inference) and `taskReturningString ==` is a method that can be expanded to that kind of function.

Here is a simplified example.

```
val equals: String => Boolean = "foo" ==

println(equals("foo"))
// true

println(equals("bar"))
// false
```

or with `+`

```
val plusTwo: Int => Int = 2 +
println(plusTwo(2))
// 4
```

`drop` from `String`

```
val drop: Int => String =  "abcd".drop
println(drop(2))
// cd
```

or `:::` from List

```
val concat: List[Int] => List[Int] = List(1,2,3) :::
println(concat(List(4,5,6)))
// List(4,5,6,1,2,3)
```

The use of _ is not always necessary if the compiler realizes that it can expand a method with missing parameters and the types are correct.

This code doesn't work because there is no way that the compiler knows the type of `equals`

```
val equals = "foo" ==
```

so I need to help it with `_`

```
val equals = "foo" == _
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer for this lies with following facts,

Fact 1: Even operators are `methods` in Scala,

```
// something like
val a = "abc" == "def"

// is actually
val a = "abc".==("def")
```

So, `taskReturningString ==` is actually method `taskReturningString.==`

Fact 2: `methods` can be converted to `functions` (by using `_`),

```
val string1 = "abc"

val func1 = string1.== _
// func1: Any => Boolean = sof.A$A0$A$A0$$Lambda$1155/266767500@12f02be4

// or if you want more specific type,
val func2: String => Boolean = string1.== _
// func2: String => Boolean = sof.A$A0$A$A0$$Lambda$1156/107885703@19459210
```

Fact 3: Scala compiler is smart. It supports `eta-expansion` which is conversion of a `method` to an appropriate `function` (to match the requirement)(if possible). So, if we tell the compiler that we want a `Function` of type `String => Boolean` and give it a method, it will smartly convert it to function.

```
// so our func3 did not need that explicit conversion using `_`

val func3: String => Boolean = string1.==
// func3: String => Boolean = sof.A$A1$A$A1$$Lambda$1161/1899231632@4843e7f0
```

Now, since your `taskReturningString` is a `Future[String]` thus `taskReturningString.map` wants an function of type `String => A` for any type `A`.

Also, `taskReturningString.==` takes an argument of type `Any` and return type of `Boolean`,

the compiler will expand it to a function `String => Boolean`,

```
val future1 = Future("abc")

val func4: String => Boolean = future1.==
// func4: String => Boolean = sof.A$A4$A$A4$$Lambda$1237/1577797787@2e682ccb

// And since `func4` will compare the argument string with `future1` for equality
// it will always return `false`

// So what you are doing is actually,
val falseResult: Future[Boolean] = future1.map(func4)
```